# SquirrelMail (Courier) IMAP Issue

Tags: imap, squirrelmail

Alright, so I'm having this issue with SquirrelMail and Courier IMAP. When I try to login to SM, it throws this error at me:

```
ERROR: Connection dropped by IMAP server.
```

The IMAP server is running on 993 without SSL (which might be the problem). How do I fix this, and I've already taken a look at the official documentation in relation to this error with no fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bill said, 993 is usually IMAPS.  Are you sure it's running without SSL? What happens when you do:

telnet serverip 993

Do you get a greeting?  If not, what about:

openssl s_client -connect serverip:993

If you get a response in either, just type:

A01 LOGOUT

It'll disconnect.

If you get a response from the first, what does it say?  If you get a response on the second, it means you are running IMAPS, which means you need to change your config/config.php settings for your imap connection (see $use_imap_tls).

As a side, Courier defaults to limiting connections from a single IP to 4 connections.  If multiple people will be using this SquirrelMail install, you'll want to increase that limit, see the MAXPERIP setting in the imapd config file.

Answer (score 0):

Port 993 is IMAPS (with SSL) dovecot may be automatically trying SSL as per standards. 
Check that the use_imap_tls option is set to false.  If at all possible enable SSL on port 993 or use port 143 IMAP.

Comment: It would appear that we have two pieces of software competiting (Dovecot and Courier), so how do I disable one and enable another?